# Closing child pop-up and refreshing the parent page

Tags: javascript, popup

I am trying to achieve the following.

1. A link on a parent page will open a new child pop-up.
2. In the child pop-up, the user enters some data and clicks “Save”.
3. Data will be saved to database and the pop-up will be closed. The parent window would be refreshed, and the data entered in the child pop-up would be displayed in the parent page.

How can this (closing a child pop-up and refreshing the parent page) be done in Javascript?

Answer (score 11):

In the pop-up window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function proceed(){
   opener.location.reload(true);
   self.close();
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="proceed()">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

In the popup's code for closing/reloading:

```
opener.location.reload();
close();
```

Answer (score 3):

parent.html

```
<a href="#" onclick='window.open("child.html","_blank","height=100,width=100,
status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");return false'>pop up</a>
```

child.html

```
<p>child window</p>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    window.opener.location.reload(true);
    window.close();
}();
</script>
```