# Parent Jsp page refresh when click on popupwindow alert box

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom-events

I am working on jsp's, I have two jsp one in configDb.jsp, in that I have written code to retrieve the values from database and display it. In this whereas I have option like newconnection.. its a popup window. When I click on that it opens popupwindow and taken the values and store them in a database, but in my parent page I am not able to display those values. After I click on the ok button in popup window, I have to refresh the parent page, then I am able to see the values which I have created few seconds back by the new connection page. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: can you post some code how you are opening a window?

Answer (score 0):

You can include this in your HTML for the popup window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function proceed(){
   opener.location.reload(true);
   self.close();
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="proceed()">
...
</form>
```

Actually you can obtain the answer by googling "[javascript refresh parent page from popup](https://encrypted.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=javascript+refresh+parent+page+from+popup&oq=javascript+refresh+parent+page+from+popup&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i30.2479.4106.1.4386.11.11.0.0.0.0.105.657.9j1.10.0...0.0.DXQ-fI2E8QE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=b971767ad7eb6c00&biw=1291&bih=700)" and you will see [stackoverflow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139657/closing-child-pop-up-and-refreshing-parent-page) :)

A better alternative without the need of refreshing the parent page can be achieved by adding a submit button listener and perform a DOM action to insert the new element with new content. This can be easily done by Javascript.

Comment: thank u for ur fast response, but its not working..my parent jsp has popup window ..on click on link in parent jsp,it opens popup & take the values & save those in database in another jsp , for example my parnt window is configDB.jsp & click the link onconfigDB.jsp, it opens properties.jsp then in properties.jsp, if we click on save button the it goes to saveconfig1.jsp.. in that alert comes., if u click on alert button , it automatically closes the pop up window.. but here my problem is after closing the popup window how can i refresh the parent page..