# Update the grid when using registration form (WebUserControl) open in apopup

Tags: c#, asp.net, webusercontrol

i have a grid view on a page and i have webusercontrol which contains the registration for and this usercontrol open in a popup and when i click finish submit of registration this will add the new entry in database. but my grid still show previos records untill i refresh the page . so how can i rebind the grid on click of Submit button of user control?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh parent page on popup window closing.

This link would be help. [Closing-child-pop-up-and-refreshing-parent-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139657/closing-child-pop-up-and-refreshing-parent-page)

Or you can check the javascript code below.

```
function refreshParent() {

  window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
  if (window.opener.progressWindow)     
  {
    window.opener.progressWindow.close()
  }
  window.close();

}
```

Comment: --> sorry i don't want to refresh the parent page because if i refresh the page then my filteration of the records will lost

Comment: you may store the filter parameters in session and set those parameters again on page post back