# How to load the grid (in Main page) after some data added in popup page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Consider I have a page with Add button and Grid.
Grid Contains some data. 
If I click Add Button ,the new popup window will open.
Popup window contains Text-boxes and Button for adding the new values to Grid.
My ques is ,how to automatically load  the grid view after adding some values in popup window?

code for popup window:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newWindow", String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}','','width=550,height=300,left=500');</script>", "PopupADD.aspx"));
}
```

Comment: Just refresh the page.   Or else view it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139657/closing-child-pop-up-and-refreshing-parent-page

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps..

```
1.Design a window to add data to gridview inside a div.
2.Show the div as popup using Javascript.
3.Bind the gridview when you click some button(like ok) in that popup window.
```