# how to passing value of session from page 2 to page 1 in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, session, file-upload, listbox

I have a listbox and button on the page 1 and when i click on the button, the page 2 will open in a new tab. In the page 2, I'm uploading photos to a folder and set the session["FileName"] value. I want when i close the page 2, names of Uploaded images are displayed in listbox.

Note: session["FileName"] = names of uploaded images.

Does anyone have an idea? Please Help me.

Thank you.

my Upload class:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{      
    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        // get the applications path 

        string uploadPath = context.Server.MapPath(context.Request.ApplicationPath + "/Temp");
        for (int j = 0; j <= context.Request.Files.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            // loop through all the uploaded files 
            // get the current file 
            HttpPostedFile uploadFile = context.Request.Files[j];

            // if there was a file uploded 
            if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                context.Session["FileName"] = context.Session["FileName"].ToString() + uploadFile.FileName+",";
                uploadFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(uploadPath, uploadFile.FileName));
            }
        }
    }
    // Used as a fix for a bug in mac flash player that makes the 
    // onComplete event not fire 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(" ");
}
```

Comment: Simple update page1, after close page2 - or do not open second page, and do everything from one page.

Comment: If this is possible, I expect it would be done via Javascript. I don't see it as an asp.net specific issue. Perhaps this might point you in the right direcion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139657/closing-child-pop-up-and-refreshing-parent-page

Comment: Thank TwentyGotoTen. That is great help.

Comment: Then an up-vote would be much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Session is a server object in ASP.NET. That means, when you create a Session on one page, you can use it on any other page, as long as the Session object wasn't Removed or expired.

Suppose you did this on page1.aspx.cs

```
Session["FileName"] = "file1";
```

then you can access it on page2.aspx.cs like this:

```
if(Session["FileName"]!=null)
    Label1.Text = (string)Session["FileName"]
```

So that way you can access Session variables only on the .aspx page or Control-derived class.

If you want to access Session variables in a Class Library Project than, do this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["FileName"]
```

also, it looks like you have created a Custom `HttpModule`.

be notified that your HTTPModule must not be dealing with any pipeline events that that occur before the session state being initialized.

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276355/can-i-access-session-state-from-an-httpmodule) to know more on how and when to access Session variables in a HttpModule

Comment: Dear Manish Mishra. Thank for help but i have two pages. page 2 will open in a new tab and in the page 2, I'll upload photos and when i close the page 2, i want the session value to be shown in the listbox of page 1. Please help.

Comment: @MortezaKarimi in that case, you will have to refresh your page1. only then it will know about the new session variable created. instead of opening a new tab, open a popup or modeldialog. that way it will be much easier